# cakephp save data is giving me an error

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to insert the following array

```
foreach($list as $l)
    {

        $data = array(

        'source_number'=> $l['Csv']['Source'],
        'destination_number'=> $l['Csv']['Destination'],
        'seconds'=> $l['Csv']['Seconds'],
        'callerID'=> $l['Csv']['CallerID'],
        'disposition'=> $l['Csv']['Disposition'],
        'cost'=> $l['Csv']['Cost'],
        'billing_cost'=> $l['Csv']['newCost']

        );
        //$total[] = $l['Csv']['newCost'];
        debug($data);
        $this->CallcenterBilling->save($data);
        unset($data);

    }
```

But it dives me this error

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function save() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\wadic\app\Controller\CallcenterBillingsController.php on line 61
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0005  708160  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0169  2775744 Dispatcher->dispatch( ) ..\index.php:96
3   0.0279  3946176 Dispatcher->_invoke( )  ..\Dispatcher.php:89
4   0.0293  4016984 Controller->invokeAction( ) ..\Dispatcher.php:107
5   0.0293  4017992 ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs( ) ..\Controller.php:473
6   0.0293  4018024 CallcenterBillingsController->import( ) ..\CallcenterBillingsController.php:0
```

what am I missing?
thanks

Comment: just checking, do you have `CallcenterBilling` in your controller's `$uses` array?

Comment: can you show the rest of the controller, and perhaps the model?

Comment: Likely just don't have access to the CallcenterBilling controller at this point in your code.  Also I think you should be doing $this->MyModel->create(); before your save when saving in a loop.

Comment: * (I meant the CallcenterBilling model, not controller)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you may sure that in CallcenterBillingsController you have CallcenterBilling model in uses: 
**public $uses = array('CallcenterBilling');**

Secondary you can optimize this by saving not in loop:
see **saveAll** method of the model

so you will get something like:

```
class CallcenterBillingController extends AppController {

  public $uses = array('CallcenterBilling');

  public function someaction() {

    $data = array();
    foreach ($list as $l) {

      $data[] = array(
          'source_number' => $l['Csv']['Source'],
          'destination_number' => $l['Csv']['Destination'],
          'seconds' => $l['Csv']['Seconds'],
          'callerID' => $l['Csv']['CallerID'],
          'disposition' => $l['Csv']['Disposition'],
          'cost' => $l['Csv']['Cost'],
          'billing_cost' => $l['Csv']['newCost']
      );
      //$total[] = $l['Csv']['newCost'];

    }
    debug($data);
    $this->CallcenterBilling->saveAll($data);
  }

}
```

ps. if this not helps, please show controller code.

Comment: The `$uses` array was removed in `2.0` in favor of `App::import` [as per the migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html)

Comment: No, it's not removed and it's not deprecated http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html. "uses" that you talk about was a function in basics.php http://api13.cakephp.org/file/cake/basics.php#function-uses

Answer (score -1):

You should implement this:

```
$this->CallcenterBilling->read(null, 1);
$this->CallcenterBilling->set(array(
   'source_number'=> $l['Csv']['Source'],
    'destination_number'=> $l['Csv']['Destination'],
    'seconds'=> $l['Csv']['Seconds'],
    'callerID'=> $l['Csv']['CallerID'],
    'disposition'=> $l['Csv']['Disposition'],
    'cost'=> $l['Csv']['Cost'],
    'billing_cost'=> $l['Csv']['newCost']
));
$this->CallcenterBilling->save();
```

This might works for you.

Comment: It won't, as the problem is `$this->CallcenterBilling` doesn't exist.

Comment: @Dunhamzzz : at least give it a try.

Comment: read the error he is receiving, he is calling save on something that is not an object, so he will not be able to call *anything* on the `$this->CallcenterBilling`. Your answer will just trigger the same error.

Comment: @Dunhamzzz : how can you dislike my answer without implementing it?

Comment: Because I can see it won't work judging by the error produce in OPs question, this is not an uncommon error.

Comment: @Dunhamzzz : then Mr. Judge, why don't you give a precise answer ?